# Create patch under Windows

Tags: windows, patch

I want to create a patch for a header in order to fix my [appveyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/MartinDelille/travistest) build. I used [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org) to create the following file:

```
--- C:/Qt/5.3/mingw482_32/include/QtGui/qopengl.h   Thu Jun 19 11:08:06 2014
+++ C:/Qt/5.3/mingw482_32/include/QtGui/qopengl2.h  Sat Nov 08 11:20:32 2014
@@ -49,6 +49,7 @@
// Windows always needs this to ensure that APIENTRY gets defined
 #if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
 # include <QtCore/qt_windows.h>
+# undef MemoryBarrier
 #endif

 // Note: Mac OSX is a "controlled platform" for OpenGL ABI so we
```

When running the patch command I get the following result:

```
C:\Users\Martin\dev\TravisTest>patch -u patch_qopengl c:\Qt\5.3\mingw482_32\include\QtGui\qopengl.h
patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.
```

What's wrong?